# How to copy file from local system to other system in C# (windows app)?

Tags: c#, file-copying

I need to load help files from my windows C# application and move/copy to other system (to its local drive).  Application (same C# windows application) on the local system will use it for help.

What needs to be done to accomplish this?

I understand `File.Copy()` but i don't know, will it hold for remote system also?

Comment: Other than 'System.IO.File.Copy("source", "destination")' using a remote share for the second part? (or \\machinename\path\\)

Comment: Is the remote machine on the same domain?
Can you guarentee that the user of your app has write access privileges on the remote machine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
File.Copy(
    @"C:\localpath\file.hlp", 
    @"\\remotemachinename\localpathonremotemachine\file.hlp");
```

Or something along those lines... the second value is a UNC path.

And in case the target location needs a login and password, the following answer is applicable: [Copy file to remote computer using remote admin credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766033/copy-file-to-remote-computer-using-remote-admin-credentials/766086#766086) (Thanks to Carlos Rendon for finding it).

Comment: But what if the remote share requires a login and password?

Comment: Then you'd need something more complicated.

Comment: found it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766033/copy-file-to-remote-computer-using-remote-admin-credentials/766086#766086

Comment: Added it to the body of the answer so it is not overlooked... thanks for the suggestion! :)

Answer (score 3):

[File.Copy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx) Copies an existing file to a new file.
The target can be a remote share (UNC).