# how to move files from one system to another system using ASp.net and c#.net

Tags: asp.net, file, file-io

Please try to suggest me how to do this.
I need to copy or move files from one system to another system.
I did this  but it saying invalid path..

```
var fileName = "Text.txt";   
var local = Path.Combine(@"C:\\public_html\\TEST\\gr_library\\", fileName );  
var remote = Path.Combine(@"XXX.XXX.X.X\\C:\\public_html\\TEST\\gr_library\\", fileName );  
File.Move(remote, local );
```

Please give some code snippet which is executable...

Comment: This is not and will never be a valid path. Is the IP address on the same network as you, or is it an over the internet transfer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put \ in the front of the ip, like \123.456.789.10\folder. Make sure that the user also has access to the remote pc.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944619/how-to-copy-file-from-local-system-to-other-system-in-c-windows-app