# How do I copy a file from a file server to a remote machine using C#?

Tags: c#

I need to automatically install products in a remote machine.
I have a client which runs my code. First of all, I need to copy product files from the file server to the remote machine. How can I copy files from the file server to the remote machine using C# from my client?
I tried use xcopy (first use code mapped the file server to remote machine.)  It works, but when the copy completes, sometimes the process "xcopy.exe" does not vanish in the remote machine. Then I cannot determine the copy jobs finished (I use wmi to query the xcopy.exe process). Can somebody have any idea for this?

Comment: does this help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944619/how-to-copy-file-from-local-system-to-other-system-in-c-sharp-windows-app

Comment: Please show us some code what you've already tried.