# Move Zip file from Local system to Remote server system(Static IP IIS server)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am dynamically creating dot net c# console application  on my local system (i'm using - this code  `sourcePath = @"D:\temp\DirectoryToZip.zip"; destFile="@"\192.8.54.227\Test" ;   System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true))`.

```
C#:
 var sourcePath = @"D:\temp\DirectoryToZip.zip";  
 var  destFile= @"\192.8.54.227\Test" ; 
 System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true))
```

I am trying file move, but it cannot working. I am trying multiple links

[How to copy file from local system to other system in C# (windows app)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944619/how-to-copy-file-from-local-system-to-other-system-in-c-sharp-windows-app)
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1136426/Copy-file-from-local-pc-to-server-using-Csharp
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/423029/how-to-copy-files-from-Local-to-remote-server-with

etc...

I want to copy this zip file to my remote server system(Static IP IIS server). I use C#

Comment: Is `Test` a share on `192.8.54.227`? and you have a typo, destfile should be `var destFile = @"\\192.8.54.227\Test" ; ` (notice the second \ at start)

Comment: why you don't use TCP and networking instead?
take a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.sendfile?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Rand Random - Thanks for your reply - i am tried already this var destFile = @"\\192.8.54.227\Test" .  This return exception error - The network path was not found.

Comment: please write "@username", this way the user will get notified about your message, I am only here because my last browser session had this page open, otherwise I wouldn't know you have written this comment

so about your error `The network path was not found.` 
you do realise you have to specify a file and not a folder your file should be copied to?
other than that can't really help, the c# works as expected, but your destination isn't accessable, could be as easy as the the server isn't running, the share doesn't have the write access rights and what not