# How to copy file from a local computer to a remote computer?

Tags: c#, file, copy

I tried with WMI but doesn't work.
I also tried [this with LogonUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766033/copy-file-to-remote-computer-using-remote-admin-credentials) but it doesnt work because LogonUser only works for local computers.

So how can I copy a file or at least get connected to the computer so it accept System.IO.File.Copy?

Comment: what is your network security setup? Are you using ActiveDirectory? Are you logged in as a domain user on the box running the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a share with that you can access on every computer, you can try `\\computername\c$`.

If your app has admin-rights, you can copy files to every location on the c:. Use `\\computername\d$` for `d:` and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's the problem. It doesnt allow me to do that, yet I have admin access level.

Comment: Ok, finally it seems that they forgot to add me in the admin group >_<
It works all good now

Answer (score 1):

You need to p/invoke [WNetUseConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385482(VS.85).aspx) to get access to the computer first, then use a UNC path to access the file and use normal file I/O.  [Here is some sample C# code](http://lookfwd.doitforme.gr/blog/media/PinvokeWindowsNetworking.cs).

You would for example access c:\test.txt on a computer named MONKEY on your LAN via a path like this: `@"\\MONKEY\c$\test.txt"`.

Comment: Is this needed to access a UNC share like `\\computername\C$`?