# File.Copy() to file server with network Credential

Tags: c#, file-io

I am writing console application which will Copy file from my local disk to file server.  This folder is protecting by username and password. `File.Copy()` method does not work. It gives permission error. [I have looked to this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766033/copy-file-to-remote-computer-using-remote-admin-credentials/766086#766086)

I have tried it but it does not work. First it was written in VB but I have changed the code to C# but there are have some errors. I don't know what does this error mean.  Maybe you can advise me other way coping  file to protected File Server

**with simple File.Copy(bla bla) it gives me "you have not permission"**

**when i converted VB code to C# it gived me error below: Attempted to read or write protected memory**

I have found solution

[You can Follow It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share)

Comment: I can advise you to post the errors.

Comment: Instead of "another way", let's try to get the way you've tried working. What kind of errors are you seeing when you convert that code?

Comment: when i converted code to C# it gived me error below: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. i am sure that i have changed it correctly but in one line i am not sure. this line is  Dim admin_token As IntPtr   i have changed it to    IntPtr admin_token = new IntPtr();

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786037/copy-files-with-authentication-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 18):

You could use the [little impersonation class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx) I wrote some years ago:

```
using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) )
{
   // code that executes under the new context.
   File.Copy( x, y );
}
```

Comment: i will lood your code later if my code will not work :-) i think your code is correct. Thanks for response

Comment: i need your help. can i sen null for Domain parameter?

Comment: You could use a single dot "." to indicate that the local account database is being used. `Environment.MachineName` could also work, I guess.

Comment: @omriman12 worst error description ever.